# Android Appium WebDriverWait throws NoSuchMethodError

Tags: android, testng, appium

I'm working on automated tests for an Android app which loads content from a web database. Since the connection and result from the database may take some time, I tried to use the following code to wait until a button (which only appears when content is loaded) is visible.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 60);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(driver.findElementById(ID))).click();
```

With `driver` being instantiated as `AndroidDriver driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);`

When I run the test that uses this code, I get the following error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait.until(Lcom/google/common/base/Function;)Ljava/lang/Object;

at Actions.Action1.main(Action1.java:47)
at Cases.Case1.main(Case1.java:43)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:104)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:645)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:851)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1177)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:129)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:112)
at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:756)
at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:610)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:387)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:382)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:340)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:289)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1293)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1218)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1133)
at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1104)
at org.testng.IDEARemoteTestNG.run(IDEARemoteTestNG.java:72)
at org.testng.RemoteTestNGStarter.main(RemoteTestNGStarter.java:123)
```

Does someone know what is the problem?
I already added Guava 21.0 and 24.1-Android to Maven XML file, but neither of them changed anything in the results.

Comment: Are you sure the problem isn't your locator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be a chicken-and-egg thing, since instead of checking for the existence of the element, you're assuming that it's in the DOM but not visible.  I would advise checking to see if it exists instead.

You could instead do a loop using findElements():

```
    while (true) {
        if (driver.findElements(By.id("com.oi.codigital:id/main_refresh_button")).size() == 0)
            break;
    }
```

Comment: The element exists, but it takes some time to load. I set the implicity wait to 70 seconds, since the timeout to the database calls is set to 60 seconds and it worked. Anyway, I tried your answer and it also worked, so thanks!

Comment: Glad I could help